# Special characters in htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm not getting any server errors, but some of my redirects are not working and simply end up at a 404.

**Example:**

```
Redirect 301 /documents/2157622/29403025/COO%20candidate%20information%20pack    /wp-content/uploads/2015/10/COO-candidate-information-pack1.pdf
```

I think this might have to do with those special characters in the URL like `%20`.

Is there any way I can get .htaccess to read and respect these characters? I only need simple 301 redirect (and I have hundreds of them).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Redirect` use `RewriteRule` in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^documents/2157622/29403025/COO(\s|\x20)candidate(\s|\x20)information(\s|\x20)pack    /wp-content/uploads/2015/10/COO-candidate-information-pack1.pdf [L,NC,R=301]
```

Use `(\s|\x20)` to match white-space.